# Installing Ubuntu - received error message "does not have app associated"

Tags: system-installation, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded Ubuntu, but when I tried to install it, I got this error message:

> This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page.

I am using Windows 10 (Version 1803).
I already went into "Apps & Features" and enabled the "Windows Subsystem for Linux."

What should be my next steps?

Comment: Where did you download Ubuntu from?  From the Ubuntu home page or from the Windows app store?  If the former, try the latter.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I installed Ubuntu and it opens in a window. However, it is not responding to any commands. I think that it is not linked to the Linux subsystem. How would I connect it and verify that it is working?